# Auto scrolling between form fields

Tags: usability, forms, android

We're mocking up a new flow for our app that collects 6 data points from a user before giving them a certain result. We collect these data points one a time (as shown below). Certain fields like phone number and zip code are of a defined length and thus as soon as the user finishes typing the data we can auto scroll her (horizontally) to the next screen, or alternatively, make him tap the 'Next' button.
Since we collect 6 data points (which for our users is a lot), auto scrolling might give the user a perception that he's going though the process faster and save her clicks. But at the same time, the user might want to review their data and then proceed to the next step.

We do give the user an option to review her data points at the end of the process and make changes if necessary.

Wanted help on what are the other tradeoffs in making a decision between the 2 choices.

[image: ZipCode]

[image: Mobile number]

Comment: The autoscroll is vertical? Why one at a time?

Comment: @Alvaro It'll be horizontal scrolling. Added to question too. We used to collect the data in a long form manner, which led to massive drop off, so experimenting with this form.

Comment: It'll certainly be interesting to see if the prospect of many separate steps (the "1/8" at the stop) will be more or less attractive to users than several fields on one screen.

Comment: In addition to @MattObee comment, it looks like the horizontal autoscroll approach is trying to fill the lack of benefits that a one page with vertical scroll had. But users might feel better filling screens one at a time even at the cost of extra clicks/taps.

Answer (score 4):

*"as soon as the user finishes typing the data we can auto scroll"*

This has an advantage and a disadvantage:

- **If** the user fills correctly the input he will have to do fewer interactions
- If the user doesn't fill correctly the input (a misspell for example) he will have to do an extra step to go back (by the way, I think there is no Step back button in your images right now)

In this situation, making interactions more convenient when information is filled correctly makes interactions more complex when information is not filled correctly. In my opinion, **it is good to enhance certain experiences but not to the detriment of others**.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go and test it for your self?

You don't ask any questions. And I assume that you need to formulate the right questions for your self first. Then it would be much easier for us to help you, and for you to help your users.

But, I'll try to navigate you for some points, so it would be easier for you.

What are the arrow at the upper-right corner(first screen) and arrow at the upper-left corner(second screen) do? If it's RTL screen, then why is it in ENG? Registration(second screen) means that *this* screen is the registration screen or the next(it is next to the arrow, isn't). Why is there no another arrow at the 2/8 screen to go back/next? Is this question mark in the circle(screen 2/8) will tell me about the arrow that is placed next to it?

I hope you understand the fact I'm aware that this question mark, for example, is probably don't have anything about the arrow next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern modeled on steppers. Prior responses are collated and compressed. The user taps on them to move back and edit. The active question is given more visual weight.

[image: questionnaire design for mobile based on steppers]

Answer (score 0):

This is fancy, but fancy interactions normally fall down under just a little bit of scrutiny.

It’s unconventional. Forms don’t work like this normally.

Because of this users may well be confused about where the input has gone or why the next input has been focused.

Then they might spend time working out what’s happened and navigating back to the previous input to make sure what they typed is actually correct rather than just technically correct (such as that it has enough characters).

If the user makes a mistake and realises it, they’ll have to navigate back. What a pain.

Instead consider:

- moving to the next field when the users submits each step of the multi-step form
- showing all 6 fields on one screen within a single-step form

If you test this in a realistic scenario with a diverse set of users you’ll probably spot these issues rather quickly.